# Re-ordering data.frame from AAABBBCCC to ABCABCABC

Tags: r

I have data.frame which is currently ordered alhphabetically by N replicates of each letter. How can I order it such that the rows look like: ABC...ABC...ABC...?

```
N=1e1
df<-data.frame(x=runif(N),y=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=N)
```

which looks like:

```
              x y
1 0.01757513 A
2 0.39505796 A
3 0.95014487 A
4 0.01757513 B
5 0.39505796 B
6 0.95014487 B
7 0.01757513 C
8 0.39505796 C
9 0.95014487 C
```

Output that I'm trying to make is:

```
A 0.4
B 0.3
C 0.2
A 0.1
B 0.3
C 0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using **data.table**

```r
library(data.table)

df <- read.table(text = "              x y
1 0.01757513 A
2 0.39505796 A
3 0.95014487 A
4 0.01757513 B
5 0.39505796 B
6 0.95014487 B
7 0.01757513 C
8 0.39505796 C
9 0.95014487 C", header = T)

setDT(df)[order(rowid(y))]
#>             x y
#> 1: 0.01757513 A
#> 2: 0.01757513 B
#> 3: 0.01757513 C
#> 4: 0.39505796 A
#> 5: 0.39505796 B
#> 6: 0.39505796 C
#> 7: 0.95014487 A
#> 8: 0.95014487 B
#> 9: 0.95014487 C
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Like this perhaps:

```r
N=1e1
df<-data.frame(x=runif(N),y=rep(c("A","B","C"),each=N))

o <-matrix( 1:nrow(df), nrow=3, byrow=T ) %>% as.vector
df[o,]
```

(It requires the data to be pretty well behaved, having the same number of distinct letters for example)

Comment: Thank you for your help and contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that is independent of the number of groups and the number of elements within each group (which may differ between groups).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(y) %>% 
  mutate(Index=row_number()) %>% 
  arrange(Index, y) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-Index)
# A tibble: 9 x 2
       x y    
   <dbl> <chr>
1 0.0176 A    
2 0.0176 B    
3 0.0176 C    
4 0.395  A    
5 0.395  B    
6 0.395  C    
7 0.950  A    
8 0.950  B    
9 0.950  C
```

It's not clear how `x` is transformed between input and output.

Comment: Thank you for your help and contribution on this.